# Getting zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element for method that worked with suds

Tags: python, soap-client, suds, zeep

I'm porting over code that was developed with `suds 0.6` over to `zeep 2.4.0`.

Previous suds code:

```
client = Client(WSDLfile, proxy=proxy, faults=True)
config = client.factory.create('perUserDataExportConfiguration')
config.param1 = 'something'
...
data = client.service.exportPerUserData(username,password,config)
```

zeep code:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(WSDLfile, strict=False, transport=transport)
config = client.type_factory('ns0').perUserDataExportConfiguration()
config.param1 = 'something'
...
data = client.service.exportPerUserData(username,password,config)
```

Then I get `zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element param_i_didnt_set`. Looking into `config.__values__` shows

```
OrderedDict([('param1', 'something'),
             ('param_i_didnt_set', None), ...])
```

The `suds` `config` object is similar in that it contains a number of keys with empty variables, but `suds` doesn't throw `ValidationErrors`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this Github issue](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/318) I saw the use of `zeep.xsd.SkipValue`. So I did a replace of any parameter with None in `config` with that:

```
for key in config:
    if config[key] is None:
        config[key] = zeep.xsd.SkipValue
```

And then `client.service.exportPerUserData(username,password,config)` worked...

Comment: This zeep.xsd.SkipValue is so useful, especially since Zeep seems to enforce validation even when the property is deemed nillable in the datacontract. Thanks a lot @raphael